# How to validate list of host names from extra variables via `assert`?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook which requires `--extra-vars` to be passed and would like to know if there is any way that validate the hostnames from the `--extra-vars` values is within the variables.

Sample playbook **`test.yml`**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    prg:
      prod_mgmt_network: "{{ ['prodsrv00']|product(range(prod_start,prod_end))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_mgmt_network: "{{ ['testsrv00']|product(range(test_start,test_end))|map('join')|list }}"
    prod_start: 4281
    prod_end: 4283
    test_start: 8281
    test_end: 8283


  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: prg.prod_mgmt_network, prg.test_mgmt_network
```

Sample command

```bash
ansible-playbook --extra-vars hostname=['prodsrv004281', 'prodsrv004282', 'testsrv008281', 'testsrv008282', 'testsrv008283', 'testsrv008284'] test.yml
```

I would like to fail the task if a hostname is not within the variable. for example, `testsrv008283` and `testsrv008284` should fail the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is the format of the extra variables. See [Defining variables at runtime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime). The key=value (INI) syntax are always interpreted as strings. You might want to test it. For example, the below play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: hostname
    - debug:
        var: hostname|type_debug
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e hostname=['host1','host2']

  hostname: '[host1,host2]'

  hostname|type_debug: str
```

There are more options for how to get a list:

- Convert the string to a list

```yaml
  hostname_list: "{{ hostname|from_yaml }}"
```

Then, you'll get

```yaml
  hostname_list:
  - host1
  - host2

  hostname_list|type_debug: list
```

- Use JSON format

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e '{"hostname": ["host1", "host2"]}'

  hostname:
  - host1
  - host2

  hostname_list|type_debug: list
```

- Put the extra variable(s) into a file. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat hostname.yml 
hostname:
  - host1
  - host2
```

Then, the below play gives the same result

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e @hostname.yml
```

For testing your case, the simplest option is to put the list into a file

```yaml
shell> cat hostname.yml
hostname:
  - prodsrv004281
  - prodsrv004282
  - testsrv008281
  - testsrv008282
  - testsrv008283
  - testsrv008284
```

---

Q: ***"Fail if hostname is not within the variable. For example, testsrv008283 and testsrv008284 should fail."***

A: Select the lists of hosts and compare the differences. For example,

```yaml
  prod_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'prodsrv') }}"
  test_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'testsrv') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  prod_hosts:
  - prodsrv004281
  - prodsrv004282

  test_hosts:
  - testsrv008281
  - testsrv008282
  - testsrv008283
  - testsrv008284
```

Evaluation of the networks gives

```yaml
  prg:
    prod_mgmt_network:
    - prodsrv004281
    - prodsrv004282
    test_mgmt_network:
    - testsrv008281
    - testsrv008282
```

The below assert will pass

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of range."
      vars:
        prod_out: "{{ prod_hosts|difference(prg.prod_mgmt_network) }}"
```

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
```

but, this one will fail

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: test_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ test_out }} out of range."
      vars:
        test_out: "{{ test_hosts|difference(prg.test_mgmt_network) }}"
```

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: test_out|length == 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: 'Hosts: [''testsrv008283'', ''testsrv008284''] out of range.'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    prg:
      prod_mgmt_network: "{{ ['prodsrv00']|
                             product(range(prod_start,prod_end))|map('join') }}"
      test_mgmt_network: "{{ ['testsrv00']|
                             product(range(test_start,test_end))|map('join') }}"
    prod_start: 4281
    prod_end: 4283
    test_start: 8281
    test_end: 8283

    prod_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'prodsrv') }}"
    test_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'testsrv') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: prg.prod_mgmt_network
    - debug:
        var: prg.test_mgmt_network
    - debug:
        var: hostname

    - debug:
        var: prod_hosts
    - debug:
        var: test_hosts

    - assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of range."
      vars:
        prod_out: "{{ prod_hosts|difference(prg.prod_mgmt_network) }}"

    - assert:
        that: test_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ test_out }} out of range."
      vars:
        test_out: "{{ test_hosts|difference(prg.test_mgmt_network) }}"
```